# Wordpress search shows protected content

Tags: plugins, search, security, previews

I have noticed many times that WordPress search results reveal protected/locked content. Is it a security issue or do search results show the webpage as viewed by the admin?

Sometimes, the content of some password protected pages is also visible in wordpress search results (using ?s=)

However, it's only the summary/preview of the webpage and not the entire content

Is it a security issue (related to login plugins? or cached pages?) or does it have to do with misconfiguration of wordpress settings?

On some websites, it shows protected content while on other websites it shows a summary of the content on that page (which is password protected)

How do you fix this problem?

Comment: Are you logged in when you’re testing this? They will appear if you’re logged in.

Comment: No, I am not logged in. I have also noticed this problem in many other wordpress websites on the internet. @JacobPeattie